# Unable to connect to AWS RDS MySQL from php

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am new to AWS and have set up a mysql RDS instance.

I am able to connect from my laptop using MySQLWorkbench but when I try to connect with the following code from one of my servers (not an aws server) I get the following error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /home/asmserverco/public_html/sms/login.php on line 28
>   Connection failed: Connection timed out

Here is the php connection code:

```html
$servername = "****.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "awsasm";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "sms";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

I have set all traffic on the instance's security group to be allowed from any IP.

why can I connect from my laptop but not my web sever?

Comment: Matt, is your security group set to specific IP or open to all (0.0.0.0/0)? Is your server running CentOS with SELinux enabled?

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, the security group is set to all as you describe above. The server s running CENTOS 6.8 and yes SELinux is enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did not modify NACLs, check that RDS allows connection to port 3306 from your server's IP. If you want to open it for all (which is not secure therefore not recommended) it should be 0.0.0.0/0.

Also, make sure 'Publicly Accessible' is set to 'yes'.

Answer (score 4):

Considering you are running CentOS with SELinux enabled it's always good idea to check audit file.

```
/var/log/audit/audit.log
```

That being said I'm certain the problem is with missing network flag. Run below as root.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

And try to access again.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if TCP_OUT port 3306 is enabled in your firewall. that did it for me. I kept whitelisting IP addresses and tweaking settings until I realized that my server was actually not allowed to communicate with the database because of CSF firewall.